# move child node to sibling node level using XSL Transform version 1

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

My XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text/text()" name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="separator" select="','"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
                <item>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>
                </item>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <item>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
                </item>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Input:

```
<root>
<text>Item1, Item2, Item3</text>
</root>
```

My Output:

```
<root>
    <text>
        <item>Item1</item>
        <item>Item2</item>
        <item>Item3</item>
    </text>
</root>
```

**My Desired Output:**

```
<root>
<item>Item1</item>
<item>Item2</item>
<item>Item3</item>
</root>
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add another template:

```
<xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

This template will match `text` and processes its child elements(without creating `<text>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is add another template that matches `text`, so that it won't get matched by the identity template to copy it. The new template just needs to carry on processing the children, but not actually copy the `text` node itself.

```
<xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, you could change the template match of your existing `tokenize` template to match the `text` node, rather than the child text nodes.

```
<xsl:template match="text" name="tokenize">
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I tried this and got an error saying "An attribute node cannot be created after the children of the containing element." @Lingamurthy CS answer worked perfectly. I got the idea from your answer though. +1.

Comment: Yes, I had originally typed `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>` in my answer, which would have given an error if your XML does have attributes in, but I edited it to be just `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>`. (Note that doing `<xsl:apply-templates />` is the same as doing `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />` so Lingamurthy's answer should be preferred here)